# Compare values in big tables in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I have two big tables in two separate spreadsheet in Excel.

lets say table A has 8k rows and table B has 70k rows.

both tables have the following columns:

```
(A) BUSINESS_UNIT
(B) LEDGER
(C) ACCOUNT
(D) AFFILIATE
(E) AMOUNT
```

I want to check if the combination of business unit, ledger, account, affiliate in table A is existing in table B.

for example:
table A

```
A     B    C      D   E
10008 CORE 123456 98  150.00
```

table B

```
A     B    C      D   E
10008 CORE 123456 98  180.00
```

in table A, the combination of columns A to D is also existing in table B, but they have different 'Amount'(column E). I want to get that difference.

Comment: Will you always have `A:D` filled in, and you just need to get `E`?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to create a CONCATENATE column combining A, B, C and D (using TEXT to fix widths if required) in both sheets. Then use VLOOKUP on these columns to return the AMOUNT

Comment: This scenario is precisely what the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) is designed for.

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, A:D are always filled in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data is laid out like this:

[image]

In `F7` you can use the following CSE formula (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=E7-INDEX($E$2:$E$3,MATCH(A7&B7&C7&D7,$A$2:$A$3&$B$2:$B$3&$C$2:$C$3&$D$2:$D$3,0))
```

<sub>You will likely want some error handling, which you can do with `=IFERROR([formula above],[do something if an error])`</sub>

Comment: This should really be a SUMIFS, no CSE needed: `=E7-SUMIFS($E$2:$E$3,$A$2:$A$3,A7,$B$2:$B$3,B7,$C$2:$C$3,C7,$D$2:$D$3,D7)`

Comment: @tigeravatar - That looks like a great answer :D You should add it.  I didn't even think about it - my brain always jumps to my beloved `Index/Match` even when it's totally overkill :P

Answer (score 0):

You should add a column in the first column of both tables, such as its values are a `Concatenate` function of the 4 values you need to match.

```
CONCATENATE         BUSINESS_UNIT   LEDGER  ACCOUNT AFFILIATE   AMOUNT
10008CORE12345698   10008           CORE    123456  98          150  

=CONCATENATE(B2,C2,D2,E2)
```

Next, you should create a `DIFFERENCE` column, where you match both tables with `VLOOKUP` and the concatenate value you just created.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$F$(Final row here),6,0)-F2
```

Comment: may I just ask what does ,6,0 mean?

Comment: `6` means to return the 6th column value of the match, thats the `Amount` value. `0` is the same as `FALSE`, which means that `VLOOKUP` should return an exact coincidence. `1` or `TRUE` makes `VLOOKUP` to return an approximate coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a helper column that concatenates all the values you want to look up, then use VLOOKUP to search for them in each table.

In both table A and table B, make a column that combines the business unit, ledger, account and affiliate fields. You can just mash them together. For instance, it would look like 10008CORE12345698.

Then, use VLOOKUP to look up your mashed-together value on both tables. Check if each value is a number, and then subtract them if so.